# Cygwin - Error Running Program on Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, shared-libraries, guile

**Operating System:** Windows 8.1

**Cygwin Version:** Latest version, as of Sept. 9, 2014.

**Guile Version:** 1.8

**Background:**

My overall goal is to install a program called "MIT Photonics Band ([MPB](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/MPB_download))" on Windows 8.1 using Cygwin. I am a new user, as I started using Cygwin a few days ago. I was able to install all required packages successfully after some troubleshooting. Eventually, I installed the MPB program using the generic ./configure, make, make install commands with slight modifications. All of this appeared to be successful.

**The Problem:**

When I try to run the executable program, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: In procedure primitive-load-path:
ERROR: Unable to find file "ice-9/boot-9.scm" in load path
```

**Attempt At Solution:**

The following is a page of the MPB installation manual:
[MPB Installation Manual - Shared Libraries](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/MPB_Installation#Paths_for_Running_.28Shared_Libraries.29).
It appears to address my issue. Note that it mentions LIBDIR and foobar. For my operating system, foobar is PATH. The LIBDIR, however, I do not know explicitly because my "make install" output did not indicate it, as the manual suggests it should have. Anyhow, I found the location of ice-9/boot-9.scm through a computer search and its directory happens to be here:
C:\cygwin64\usr\share\guile\1.8\ice-9
Hence, I ran the following command (again, for a Windows 8.1 operating system) in bash:

```
$ export PATH="/usr/share/guile/1.8/ice-9:$PATH"
```

However, note that when I run $PATH, I get this message:

```
-bash: /usr/share/guile/1.8/ice-9:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

I also tried:

```
$ export GUILE_LOAD_PATH="/usr/share/guile/1.8/ice-9:$GUILE_LOAD_PATH"
```

That yielded:

```
-bash: /usr/share/guile/1.8/ice-9:: No such file or directory
```

Furthermore, I tried to copy and paste the "ice-9" folder in various locations for a quick and sloppy solution, but it was to no avail. I searched online for answers as some users have had an issue with the program not finding the ice-9/boot-9.scm file in the past. I could not get my problem solved.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information. I appreciate the help!

**EDIT:** In response to the first user's post, I used the command echo $PATH and the following was the output:

```
/usr/share/guile/1.8:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86_64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/AMD APP/bin/x86:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2013a/runtime/win64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2013a/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/MATLAB Compiler Runtime/v81/runtime/win64:/usr/lib/lapack
```

Note that the problem still persists.

**EDIT 2:**
So I opened the "load.scm" file for GUILE and I found this line:

```
(define load-path '("/usr/share/emacs/20.7/lisp/"
            "/usr/share/emacs/20.7/lisp/emacs-lisp/"))
```

I tried to add /usr/share/guile/1.8/ to these directories, but that didn't do anything either. Can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: You can't look at the `PATH` environment variable by running `$PATH`. You need to use `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Alright I did that and it correctly output the directory. I have edited my original post to show what the output was. However, I am still receiving the same error when I run mpb.exe.